# Biztalk IOC Container

Tags: inversion-of-control, biztalk

Please could someone tell me if it is possible to effectively use a Dependency Injection/IOC 
Container tool in Biztalk?

Also, does Biztalk contain some form of bootstrapping to create the object graph dependencies at some suitable initialization stage, or can perform some form of lazy loading?

Comment: Have a look here - author uses Unity - http://smashbts.blogspot.com/2011/01/using-unity-in-biztalk-solutions.html -

Answer (score 0):

The BizTalk ESB toolkit also relies on the Unity application block so you might try building some custom ESB components to handle the IoC. If you did this you would probably have to go with the ESB toolkit or at least reference it.

Thanks,